# cshell text editor

Tags: editors, csh

Is there any text editor with highighting for cshell scripts that includes code folding? (Preferable something with a less steep learning curve than vim and emacs)

I haven't been able to find anything that fits cshell scripts, many offer highlighting for bash or c scripts, but neither of that properly fits cshell scripts. I normally use Kate and Komodo which have the features I need for other scripts, but not for cshell scripts.

Comment: There's a reason for that. C Shell scripts are syntactically ambiguous. Use the C Shell for interactive work, certainly, but don't try writing scripts in it. Really. (Want [ten](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt) or more [reasons](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html)?)

Comment: Unfortunately I have a huge pile of someone else's code that I have to work on which is written in cshell and can't avoid it.
With C shell scripts being syntactically ambigous, is there ANY highlighting mode that would fit the best? 
I've only so far managed to make some sense out of choosing **shell** highlighting in **gedit** which highlights the code "sort of alright" but doesn't offer code folding.